# gtest dependency for Bazel java_tools build?

Tags: bazel

I am trying to follow the instructions for contributors here:

https://bazel.build/contributing.html

I have a successful build off of master (i.e. bazel build //src:bazel), but the doc suggests also "you might want to build the various tools Bazel uses." I am trying to do that, for example:

```
cd src/java_tools/singlejar
bazel build //...
```

but it fails with:

```
ERROR: /Users/.../bazel/third_party/protobuf/3.2.0/BUILD:621:1: no such target '//external:gtest': target 'gtest' not declared in package 'external' defined by /Users/plaird/scone/public/bazel/WORKSPACE and referenced by '//third_party/protobuf/3.2.0:test_plugin'.
```

Do I need to build gtest locally, and then add it to the WORKSPACE file?

Answer (score 1):

`bazel build //...`, no matter where you invoke it, will build everything in the project.  It looks like what you probably want is `bazel build //src/java_tools/singlejar/...`, which will build all targets under that directory.

In general, though, you probably don't need to compile singlejar separately.  I've been working on Bazel for several years and 99% of the time you don't have to build the tools separately.

In terms of the error you're getting, it would be nice if we could get `//...` building, but it hasn't been a huge priority.  The protobuf code build is weird and I don't recommend trying to debug it, just jump into whatever you want to actually work on.